# Representation of Tangent vectors of Real Projective Space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, quotient-spaces

**I am reading representations to tangent vectors of quotient manifolds from [chapter 3 of Optimization on matrix manifolds](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/absil/Absil_Chap3.pdf), specifically trying to understand how the tangent vector representations at two points, $\bar{\xi}_x$ and $\bar{\xi}_{\alpha x}$, are related.**

The real projective space $\Bbb{RP}^{n-1}$ is the quotient $\Bbb{R}^n_{*}/\sim$, where $x \sim y$ if and only if there is an $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}_*$ such that $y=\alpha x$. The equivalence class of a point $x$ of $\Bbb{R}_*$ is 
$$
[x]=\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))=x \mathbb{R}_{*}:=\left\{x \alpha: \alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{*}\right\}
$$

The vertical space at a point $x \in \Bbb R^n_*$ is $
\mathcal{V}_{x}=x \mathbb{R}:=\{x \alpha: \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}
$

A suitable choice of horizontal distribution is $
\mathcal{H}_{x}:=\left(\mathcal{V}_{x}\right)^{\perp}:=\left\{z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: x^{T} z=0\right\}
$

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary smooth function and define $\bar{f}:=f \circ \pi: \mathbb{R}_{*}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Consider the function $g: x \mapsto \alpha x,$ where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary nonzero scalar.

I was able to understand the following:

1) $\operatorname{D} g(x) \left[\bar{\xi}\right] = \alpha \bar{\xi}_x $, because $g(x)$ is a linear map.

2) $\operatorname{D} \bar{f}(g(x))\left[\operatorname{D} g(x)\left[\bar{\xi}_{x}\right]\right]=\operatorname{D} \bar{f}(x)\left[\bar{\xi}_{x}\right]$ because $\bar f(g(x)) = f(\pi(g(x))) = f(\pi(x)) =\bar f(x)$.

Using the above two facts, we can write that 
\begin{align*} \operatorname{D} \bar f(\alpha x)[\alpha \bar{\xi}_x] &= \operatorname{D} \bar{f}(x)\left[\bar{\xi}_{x}\right] \\ & = \operatorname{D} f(\pi(x)) \left[ \xi_x \right] \\ & = \operatorname{D} f(\pi(\alpha  x)) \left[ \xi_x \right] \end{align*}

> The book claims that since the above equation is valid for any smooth
>   function $f$, this implies $\operatorname{D}\pi(\alpha x)\left[ \alpha
> \bar{\xi}_x  \right] = \xi$. This, along with the fact that $\alpha
> \bar{\xi}_x$ is an element of $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha x}$, implies that
>   $\bar{\xi}_{\alpha x}=\alpha \bar{\xi}_{x}$.

Q1) How does $ \operatorname{D} \bar f(\alpha x)[\alpha \bar{\xi}_x] = \operatorname{D} f(\pi(\alpha  x)) \left[ \xi_x \right] $ imply $\operatorname{D}\pi(\alpha x)\left[ \alpha
\bar{\xi}_x  \right] = \xi$ ?

Q2) What is the guarantee that $\alpha \bar{\xi}_x$ belong to $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha x}$?

Edit: 
I think I figured out the reasoning for Q2 - $\mathcal{H}_{\alpha x} = \left\{z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \alpha x^{T} z=0\right\}$ - therefore $\alpha \bar{\xi}_x \in \mathcal{H}_{\alpha x}$.